# CoreSpolight does not work on device such as iphone 5?

Tags: search, beta, xcode7, ios9, corespotlight

I updated my phone system to iOS 9 beta, and ran my project with my phone device, but the coreSpotlight does not work, where in my simulator it works.
Any body has such a problem ?

Comment: have you added a code in your app for CoreSpotlight to work?

Comment: YES, I Said my Code works well on My iphone simulator, but the Same code does not Work in my deveices.

Comment: ahh.. Please paste code..

Comment: Post your code to get an answer...

Comment: If you upgraded your phone, it takes a while for the index to build. Give it several hours to finish, and try again.